# Setting Global Var and calling it in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, variables, global-variables

I am trying to set a global var and then calling it in an HTML file

```
var test = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
    function test() {
        alert("test");
    }
});
```

In the HTML part i tried doing this and it did not work. I also tried window.onload method

```
document.write(test);
```

Comment: It might be helpful to post more of what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to `document.write(test)` inside of the `document.ready`?  If not that line serves no purpose.  If you are trying to set test at the beginning of the script and use it elsewhere then in theory what you were doing would have worked.  It ultimately seems like there is a better solution to whatever your problem is, but more information will be needed to get you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer without needing to use JQuery:

```
var test = 'Test Variable'; //initialises the variable 'test'

window.onload = function() {
    alert(test);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to alert the variable `test`, not the string `"test"`, as in:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert(test);
    });
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Invent-Animate I think this does answer the question

Comment: @Invent-Animate This answer could be a lot better, but it does not appear to be VLQ (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161095/do-one-line-of-code-answers-count-as-vlq) or NAA (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag).

Comment: @apsillers Understood. I thought there was a function that required no code-only answers to have some text, but oh well.